# Disable double tap on Web App

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap for my mobile app.
I have some links and buttons with `onClick` event attached

```
 <li onclick="func();"></li>
```

I having problems when user double tap, can I somehow disabled it for current DIV ?

Comment: You can disable button on first tap and then enabled it after few seconds.

Comment: I have a big list, I don't want to disable it for others `<li>`, can you show an example how to handle it for each `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a id to your `<li id="someid">`

Then

```
$('#someid').dblclick(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

To prevent double click on multiple tags, just use a `class` on those li tags, and use the same code

```
 $('.someClass').dblclick(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```